# If I import Ownable and MyClass inherits from it, do I need to migrate the Ownable at all?

Tags: truffle-migration, inheritance

I'm a bit confused about migrations. I've just been told to use 1_migration.js file per contract, except maybe in the case of imports. I am going to change these migrations back to one per migration, but what about the first 2 contracts-- Do I need that first line and corresponding first call to `.deploy(Ownable)`. Thank you for helping.

**`2_deploy_contracts.js`**

```
var Ownable = artifacts.require("./Ownable.sol");
var OmniCAT = artifacts.require("./OmniCAT.sol");
var IronLevels = artifacts.require("./IronLevels.sol");
var Dass42 = artifacts.require("./Dass42.sol");

// Make sure Ownable migrates first since OmniCat inherits
module.exports = function(deployer) {
  deployer.deploy(Ownable);
  deployer.deploy(OmniCAT);
  deployer.deploy(IronLevels);
  deployer.deploy(Dass42);  
};

contract OmniCAT is Ownable // imports Ownable
contract IronLevels is OmniCAT
contract Dass42 is OmniCAT
```

Answer (score 3):

You do not need to explicitly deploy any contracts you inherit from, or any contracts that are deployed during the deployment of another contract. For instance, if you have:

```
contract A is B {

}
```

Contract B does not need to be deployed at all.

Additionally, if you have:

```
contract A is B {
    C cInstance = new C();
}
```

Then `C` will be deployed automatically as part of A's deployment.